# Turn off search history on Chrome?

Tags: google-account, google, chrome-for-android, privacy, search-history

If I search for for example "lemon" in the address bar in Chrome on Android, days later if I start typing "L" it will show "lemon" in bold text as a suggestion.

I have already gone to the [Activity Controls](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols) and turned off everything there except "Device information".

I simply can not find anything to turn off this behaviour, but surely there's got to be a setting for it??

Answer (score 0):

The setting might be for future prediction. In your case you have to delete from history. So maybe clear the data.

Or more specifically as you asked for chrome Android, long press on the prediction and a pop-up will come stating "Remove suggestion from history?". Tap yes.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have to manually delete every suggestion. I want to disable them completely.

Comment: You can clear your history on close for Chrome. "Remember history until I close..." or something to that affect.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Chrome is designed that way. The easiest way to avoid these is to always use Incognito mode so that it does not keep any history but you cannot do things like opening previously closed tabs either since nothing is kept. On most Android, if you leave Chrome in an Incognito tab, it stays that way until you open a regular one, so it not time consuming to simply stay Incognito.